# Converting Australian coordinates (EPSG:3112) for mapping in R

Tags: coordinate-system, r, coordinates, geolocation, australia

I'm trying to map [road accidents in Australia](https://data.sa.gov.au/data/dataset/21386a53-56a1-4edf-bd0b-61ed15f10acf/resource/446afe5b-4e01-4cdf-a281-edd25aaf3802/download/road-crashes-in-sa-2014-16.zip), which comes with x and y coordinates (e.g., x = 1328459.1 and y = 1670878 for Adelaide) as well as the following information:

```
PROJECTION LAMBERT
UNITS METERS
DATUM GDA94 SEVEN /* GDA94 SPHEROID GRS80 PARAMETERS
-28 00 00 /* 1st standard parallel
-36 00 00 /* 2nd standard parallel
135 00 00 /* Central meridian
-32 00 00 /* Latitude of projections origin
1000000 /* False easting (meters)
2000000 /* False northin (meters)
END
```

Using R and [this list](http://proj4.org/parameters.html#parameter-list), I tried to translate it as follows

```
# Projection for accident coordinates (EPSG:3112)
proj <- "+proj=lcc +lat_1=-28 +lat_2=-36 +lat_0=-32 +lon_0=135 +init=epsg:3112 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"

# Code spatial points
points <- proj4::project(accidents[, c("ACCLOC_X", "ACCLOC_Y")], proj = proj, inverse = TRUE)
accidents$longitude <- points$x
accidents$latitude <- points$y
names(accidents)[names(accidents) == "longitude"] <- "LONG"
names(accidents)[names(accidents) == "latitude"] <- "LAT
```

before mapping, but my approach appears to be incorrect given the resulting ggplot2-map (shapefiles were obtained from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/50m/cultural/ne_50m_admin_0_countries.zip) and subsetted to Australia):

[image]

Does anyone have an idea where the error is?

Comment: you might like https://github.com/ropenscilabs/ozroaddeaths

Comment: Also you'd need `accidents$longitude <- points[,1]` and `[,2]` for y, as it's a matrix not a data frame.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
PROJECTION LAMBERT
UNITS METERS
DATUM GDA94 SEVEN /* GDA94 SPHEROID GRS80 PARAMETERS
-28 00 00 /* 1st standard parallel
-36 00 00 /* 2nd standard parallel
135 00 00 /* Central meridian
-32 00 00 /* Latitude of projections origin
1000000 /* False easting (meters)
2000000 /* False northin (meters)
END
```

should be [EPSG:3107 - GDA94 / SA Lambert](https://epsg.io/3107). This is its Proj4 string:

```
+proj=lcc +lat_1=-28 +lat_2=-36 +lat_0=-32 +lon_0=135 +x_0=1000000 +y_0=2000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

Comment: Is there a way to convert it in QGIS ?